# jQuery / Javascript replace multiple occurences not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace multiple occurrences of a string and nothing seems to be working for me. In my browser or even when testing online. Where am I going wrong?

```
str = '[{name}] is happy today as data-name="[{name}]" won the match today. [{name}] made 100 runs.';

str = str.replace('/[{name}]/gi','John');

console.log(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SXTd4/

I got that example from [here](http://www.moreonfew.com/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript/), and that too wont work.

Answer (score 2):

You must not quote regexes, the correct notation would be:

```
str = str.replace(/\[{name}\]/gi,'John');
```

Also, you have to escape the `[]`, because otherwise the content inside is treated as character class.

Updating your [fiddle accordingly makes it work](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/SXTd4/3/).

There are two ways declaring regexes:

```
// literal notation - the preferred option
var re = /regex here/;
// via constructor
var re = new Regexp('regex here');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not put your regex in quotes and you need to escape `[]`

Simply use

```
str = str.replace(/\[{name}\]/gi,'John');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SXTd4/2/)

Answer (score 1):

While there are plenty of regex answers here is another way:

```
str = str.split('[{name}]').join('John');
```

Comment: Interestingly, this is faster in the new chromes: http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-split-join

Answer (score 0):

The characters [ ] { } should be escaped in your regular expression.